# Error al contar el mismo dia

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un sistema que calcula la cantidad de días pero el problema es que el cliente quiere que el día actual también me los sume. Ejemplo: si yo elijo hoy 13-12-2018 al 15-12-2018, me da como resultado 2 días y tediar que contar 3 días.

script.js

```
function data(valor){
    let ingreso = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    let retiro = document.getElementById("retiro").value;
    let fechaInicio = new Date(ingreso).getTime();
    let fechaFin    = new Date(retiro).getTime();
    let diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio; //Diferencia en milisegundos
    let dias = diff/(1000*60*60*24); //Diferencia en dias
    document.getElementById("totaldias").value = dias;
    document.getElementById("valor").value = dias*valor;
    //document.getElementById("dolares").value = valor*tasa_cambio;
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
    $tarjeta = 200;
    $efectivo = $tarjeta*0.5;
?>

<input type="date" name="ingreso" id="ingreso" autocomplete="off">
<input type="date" name="salida" id="retiro" autocomplete="off" onChange="data(<?php echo $tarjeta;?>)">
<input type="text" name="dias" id="totaldias" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final tu problema se reduce a añadirle un día extra a la diferencia entre fechas. Puedes hacerlo (al menos) de dos maneras.

**Usando el objeto Date**

Puedes usar el objeto Date, que gestiona bien los pasos de mes y año, usando:

`let fechaFin = new Date(retiro) + 1)`

El problema es que eso te va a dar como resultado un `string`. Puedes pasarlo a Date y luego hacer el getTime:

`let fechaFin = new Date(new Date(retiro) + 1)).getTime()`

**Usando milisegundos**

Otra opción es añadir directamente a la diferencia los milisegundos que tiene un día:

`let diff = (fechaFin - fechaInicio) + (24*60*60*1000);`

Comment: Gracias @ale-sanchez, no sabia como poder sumarlo, lo estaba haciendo desde `php` pero me daba un resultado que iba con la fecha, es por eso que puse vario datos referenciales. Muchas gracias